# Refresh content in a <div> tag of a portlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, liferay, portlet

I have a problem with my Liferay. I am doing the following:

```
function deleting() {
    <portlet:actionURL var="deletePolyURL"> 
        <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/deletePoly.jsp" /> 
    </portlet:actionURL>  

    <portlet:renderURL var="listingURL"> 
        <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/listing.jsp" /> 
    </portlet:renderURL>

    $.post(
        "<%=deletePolyURL%>",
        {
            ids:ch.toString()
        },
        function(per) {
              $("#WRAPlist").load("<%=listingURL%>");
               }
    );
}
```

The `<div>` is reloaded, but in this `<div>` the whole Liferay page is loaded instead of just my page, see right-hand-side of the image.

[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

deletePoly.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>


<%
            {
              //String st = request.getParameter("ids");
              String st = ParamUtil.getString(request,"ids");
              out.println("NE TORT");
                        String[] id_str;
                        id_str=st.split(",");
              Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                Connection connect= null;
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");
                Statement state = null;
                state = connect.createStatement();
                int id;
                String sql1="";
                String sql2="";
                for(int i=0;i<id_str.length;i++)
                {
                    id=Integer.parseInt(id_str[i]);
                    sql1="DELETE FROM filestatus WHERE id=?";
                    PreparedStatement stmt1 = connect.prepareStatement(sql1);
                    stmt1.setInt(1, id);
                    stmt1.execute();
                    sql2="DELETE FROM filedata WHERE id=?";
                    PreparedStatement stmt2 = connect.prepareStatement(sql2);
                    stmt2.setInt(1, id);
                    stmt2.execute();
                }
                state.close();
                connect.close();
                Integer per=1;
                out.println(per);
              }

         %>
```

listing.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection conn= null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis","postgres","123456");
Statement sta = null;
sta = conn.createStatement();
String fileName= "";
Integer fileId=null;
String fileStatus ="";

ResultSet r=sta.executeQuery("SELECT id, name, status FROM filestatus");
String acc="Принят                   ";
while(r.next())
{
    fileId=r.getInt("id");
    fileName=r.getString("name");
    fileStatus=r.getString("status");   
    if(fileStatus.equalsIgnoreCase(acc))
    {
        out.write("<input type='checkbox' class='myclass' id='check"+fileId+"' name='"+fileName+"' value='"+fileId+"'/><label for=check"+fileId+">"+fileName+"</label><br>");   
  }
    else
    {
        out.write("<input type='checkbox' class='myclass' id='check"+fileId+"' name='"+fileName+"' value='"+fileId+"'/><label for=check"+fileId+" style='color:blue'>"+fileName+"</label><br>");

    }
}
r.close();
sta.close();
conn.close();

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Im refresh question.

Comment: Okay i find a answer. Right syntax: `function deleting()
   {
    <portlet:renderURL var="deletePolyURL"> 
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/deletePoly.jsp" /> 
    </portlet:renderURL>  
    //<portlet:renderURL var="listingURL"> 
    //<portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/listing.jsp" /> 
    //</portlet:renderURL>  
     $.post(
      "<%=deletePolyURL%>",
       {ids:ch.toString()},
        function(per){
        //$("#WRAPlist").load("<%=listingURL%>");
         jQuery("#WRAPlist").load('<%= request.getContextPath() %>/listing.jsp');
      }
      );`

Comment: instead of putting this as a comment you can actually put it as an answer and accept it as an answer if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you need a `<portlet:resourceURL>` instead of a renderURL to load the `jsp` since it is an ajax request and you would need to use the `serveResource` method in your portlet class to load the `listing.jsp`.

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="listingURL"> 
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/listing.jsp" /> 
</portlet:resourceURL>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its broken again. I dont do anything with this code just add portlet i project. I try `<portlet:resourceURL>` but my deletePoly.jst dont want work. Can you say my mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through resource-handling to handle the whole Ajax call yourself, you can also limit the reply to contain just the portlet, not the whole page:

```
<%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayWindowState" %>

<portlet:actionURL var="deletePolyURL" windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE.toString() %>"> 
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/deletePoly.jsp" /> 
</portlet:actionURL>
```

See if this helps - otherwise you should use `<portlet:resourceURL>` as Prakash suggests (and handle the process in the resource-serving method of your portlet.

Comment: Nothing to change. In fireBug i see that parametrs sended in `deletePoly.jsp` but content dont deleted from data base. Im not sure but before im add portlet in project all was fine. Any way when i use this `deletePoly.jsp` im servlet its work.